# problems importing dependencies for first java programme

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm a Python developer and I've never used Java before.
I am trying to make a basic little selenium script but I have no idea how to point my app to the correct jar file (at least I think that's the problem).

I downloaded a zip folder from Selenium's website with a whole bunch of jar files inside of it.

Since I am trying to import the following package:

```java
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
```

I would expect a file called `org`, with a class called `openqa` etc...

My whole script is:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "hello world lol";
        System.out.println(x);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/jda test/q4/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

The actual jar files I have:

```
C:\Users\tgmjack\Desktop\java\New folder (40)>dir

Volume in drive C has no label. Volume Serial Number is C037-C26A
Directory of C:\Users\tgmjack\Desktop\java\New folder (40)
22/01/2024  18:39    <DIR>          . 
22/01/2024  18:39    <DIR>         .. 
01/01/2010  00:00           166,533 CHANGELOG 
22/01/2024  18:39    <DIR>          lib 
01/01/2010  00:00            11,365 LICENSE 
01/01/2010  00:00                89 NOTICE 
01/01/2010  00:00           180,147 selenium-api-4.16.1-sources.jar 01/01/2010  00:00           230,724 selenium-api-4.16.1.jar 01/01/2010  00:00            10,463 selenium-chrome-driver-4.16.1-sources.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00            14,949 selenium-chrome-driver-4.16.1.jar 01/01/2010  00:00            24,164 selenium-chromium-driver-4.16.1-sources.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00            36,672 selenium-chromium-driver-4.16.1.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00           676,071 selenium-devtools-v118-4.16.1-sources.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00         1,419,939 selenium-devtools-v118-4.16.1.jar 01/01/2010  00:00           676,465 selenium-devtools-v119-4.16.1-sources.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00         1,422,009 selenium-devtools-v119-4.16.1.jar 01/01/2010  00:00           684,866 selenium-devtools-v120-4.16.1-sources.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00         1,438,429 selenium-devtools-v120-4.16.1.jar 01/01/2010  00:00           474,307 selenium-devtools-v85-4.16.1-sources.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00         1,008,603 selenium-devtools-v85-4.16.1.jar 01/01/2010  00:00            10,544 selenium-edge-driver-4.16.1-sources.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00            15,260 selenium-edge-driver-4.16.1.jar 01/01/2010  00:00           118,441 selenium-firefox-driver-4.16.1-sources.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00            83,029 selenium-firefox-driver-4.16.1.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00            39,906 selenium-http-4.16.1-sources.jar 01/01/2010  00:00            79,908 selenium-http-4.16.1.jar 01/01/2010  00:00            11,954 selenium-ie-driver-4.16.1-sources.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00            16,843 selenium-ie-driver-4.16.1.jar 01/01/2010  00:00               288 selenium-java-4.16.1-sources.jar 01/01/2010  00:00               545 selenium-java-4.16.1.jar 21/01/2024  23:32        27,512,986 selenium-java-4.16.1.zip 01/01/2010  00:00            41,665 selenium-json-4.16.1-sources.jar 01/01/2010  00:00            70,921 selenium-json-4.16.1.jar 01/01/2010  00:00             6,399 selenium-manager-4.16.1-sources.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00         8,888,227 selenium-manager-4.16.1.jar 01/01/2010  00:00            17,405 selenium-os-4.16.1-sources.jar 01/01/2010  00:00            28,113 selenium-os-4.16.1.jar 01/01/2010  00:00           282,337 selenium-remote-driver-4.16.1-sources.jar 01/01/2010  00:00           485,056 selenium-remote-driver-4.16.1.jar 01/01/2010  00:00            17,020 selenium-safari-driver-4.16.1-sources.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00            27,401 selenium-safari-driver-4.16.1.jar 01/01/2010  00:00            87,425 selenium-support-4.16.1-sources.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00           191,651 selenium-support-4.16.1.jar
```

and inside the `lib` folder theres also

```
C:\Users\tgmjack\Desktop\java\New folder (40)\lib\>dir
Volume in drive C has no label. Volume Serial Number is C037-C26A
Directory of C:\Users\tgmjack\Desktop\java\New folder (40)\lib
22/01/2024  18:39    <DIR>          . 
22/01/2024  18:39    <DIR>          .. 
01/01/2010  00:00             3,278 auto-service-annotations-1.1.1.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00         4,192,244 byte-buddy-1.14.5.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00           224,000 checker-qual-3.33.0.jar 01/01/2010  00:00            54,458 commons-exec-1.3.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00            16,518 error_prone_annotations-2.18.0.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00           146,981 failsafe-3.3.2.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00             4,644 failureaccess-1.0.1.jar 01/01/2010  00:00         3,041,611 guava-32.1.2-jre.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00             9,608 j2objc-annotations-2.8.jar 01/01/2010  00:00            20,587 jsr305-3.0.2.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00             2,249 listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00           140,641 opentelemetry-api-1.28.0.jar 01/01/2010  00:00             6,323 opentelemetry-api-events-1.28.0-alpha.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00            48,020 opentelemetry-context-1.28.0.jar 01/01/2010  00:00            11,482 opentelemetry-exporter-logging-1.28.0.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00             7,484 opentelemetry-extension-incubator-1.28.0-alpha.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00             7,015 opentelemetry-sdk-1.28.0.jar 01/01/2010  00:00            43,405 opentelemetry-sdk-common-1.28.0.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00            40,441 opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-1.28.0.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00            16,874 opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-spi-1.28.0.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00            48,054 opentelemetry-sdk-logs-1.28.0.jar 01/01/2010  00:00           262,604 opentelemetry-sdk-metrics-1.28.0.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00           118,848 opentelemetry-sdk-trace-1.28.0.jar 
01/01/2010  00:00            40,428 opentelemetry-semconv-1.28.0-alpha.jar
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code if that helps.

The error message I get is:

"The import org.openqa cannot be resolved"

How should I fix this?

Comment: Have you read https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_library/ ?

Comment: Probably, you need to add the library to the Java build path. I've never used VS Code for Java, but from looking through the internet, it seems that you need to add it on the 'Referenced Libraries' tab.

Answer (score 1):

If I download [the current selenium release](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases/download/selenium-4.16.0/selenium-java-4.16.1.zip) and then unpack it into a subdirectory called `selenium` adjacent to your code, I can successfully compile it like this:

```
javac -cp ./selenium/selenium-api-4.16.1.jar:./selenium/selenium-chromium-driver-4.16.1.jar:./selenium/selenium-chrome-driver-4.16.1.jar:./selenium/selenium-remote-driver-4.16.1.jar hello.java
```

And then I can run it like this:

```
java -cp ./selenium/selenium-api-4.16.1.jar:./selenium/selenium-chromium-driver-4.16.1.jar:./selenium/selenium-chrome-driver-4.16.1.jar:./selenium/selenium-remote-driver-4.16.1.jar:. hello
```

But that's ugly and will break as soon as I use something that requires an additional jar file.

---

The typical way of handling this in Java is to use a build tool like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/). Among other things, these tools let you declare your dependencies and will automatically ensure that those dependencies are available to you at compile time.

Using Gradle, we might initialize a new project like this:

```
mkdir hello
cd hello
gradle init --type java-application --dsl groovy \
  --package hello --project-name hello  \
  --test-framework junit-jupiter --no-incubating
```

This will create a project structure for you that looks like this:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   └── java
│       │       └── hello
│       │           └── App.java
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── hello
│                   └── AppTest.java
├── gradle
│   ├── libs.versions.toml
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── settings.gradle
```

In `app/build.gradle`, declare your dependencies. There is already a `dependencies` block in that file; modify it to look like this:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation libs.junit.jupiter
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.16.1'
}
```

(Here we're declaring Selenium as an `implementation` dependency, which means it is required by your final application. Typically Selenium is listed as a `testImplementation` dependency and is used only for running tests.)

Then place your existing code in `app/src/main/java/hello/App.java`:

```
package hello;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "hello world lol";
        System.out.println(x);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/jda test/q4/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

}
```

And finally, remove the test from `./app/src/test/java/hello/AppTest.java`, because it is no longer applicable.

Now you should be able to run:

```
gradle build
```

And then to run your project:

```
gradle run
```

---

If you're using a modern Java IDE, the IDE can probably take care of a lot of this for you.